# Xamarin forms: Multiple navigation patterns in the same app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can we have multiple navigation patterns in a single app?

In my app.xaml page I added a function

```
void SetUpNavigation()
        {
            var page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<LaunchPageModel>();
            var navPage = new FreshNavigationContainer(page);
            MainPage = navPage;
        }
```

But after a user signs in I want to use master detail page. Is there a way to do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just have to set the `MainPage` of your app again. In our projects, we use a helper class which have a method `Restart` with following logic:

```
public static void Restart(View view, NavigationType navtype)
{
    // Reset the mainpage depending on the navigation type
    if (navtype == NavigationType.RestartWithMasterPage)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterPage(view);
    }
    else if (navtype == NavigationType.Restart)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(view);
    }
    else
    {
        // Just show the page
        Application.Current.MainPage = view;
    }
}
```

The NavigationType is an enum:

```
public enum NavigationType
{
    Normal,
    Restart,
    RestartWithMasterPage
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the helper class. When a user click on a button say SignIn, it will call the restart function and `Application.Current.MainPage = SetupMasterDetailNav() ` the current main page will call a 
`public Page SetupMasterDetailNav()
  {
   var masterDetail = new FreshMvvm.FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer();
   masterDetail.AddPage<LoginPageModel>("Login");
   masterDetail.AddPage<RegistrationPageModel>("Register");
   masterDetail.Init("x");
   MainPage = masterDetail;
   return MainPage;
  }`
But it still is on same page. I am not able to change the navigation.